# Contains Result to be similar to Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `Person` with a column `FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(100)`. I created a full-text index on this column `FIRST_NAME`.

I write this simple query :

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME
FROM Person
WHERE CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, '"Sam*"')
```

It doesn't return the rows from `Person` who have a `FIRST_NAME` like 'Sam xx' Or 'Sam-Y'

But when I wrote `CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME , 'Sam')` it returned 'Sam xx' and 'Sam-Y' but it did not return Sami, Samy or Samxx...

All I want is the same result that I can get with `Like 'Sam%'`

Comment: Full-text search doesn't work the way you probably think it does. The indexer (an asynchronous "crawl" process) breaks up the source text into words (what it calls "tokens") and catalogs the words that it finds in its indexes. I would have expected `CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, '"Sam*"')` to return a match for the `Sam xx` row, though, so perhaps it hadn't finished building the index when you tried your query.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I execute this `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TableName, * FROM sys.fulltext_indexes;`  and I get the `crawl_type = 'U' ` for table `Person` but still the same the `CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME, '"Sam*")' ` doesn't return the FIRST_NAME contains Sam with space or - .

Comment: Perhaps if you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76793166/edit) your question to include the table DDL, the `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG` and `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` commands you used and some sample data somebody might be able to reproduce your problem and provide a solution.